# Why does VPMOVMSKB appear to produce incorrect results?

Tags: x86, x86-64, simd, bitmask, avx2

According to the Intel documentation, `vpmovmskb` does:

> Instruction: vpmovmskb r32, ymm
>
> Create mask from the most significant bit of each 8-bit element in a, and store the result in dst.

According to GDB, I have a vector in the `%ymm0` register with this value:
`v32_int8 = {0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}`.

After I step over the instruction `vpmovmskb %ymm0,%eax`, I would expect to get a 4-byte bitmask that looks like: 0b`00100000'10000010'00001000'00100000`. But what I actually get in `%eax`, according to GDB, is 0b`00000100'00010000'01000001'00000100`. I'm very confused by this. It looks like the result I expect is bitshifted by 3, but I have no idea why.

Does anyone here know what I could be missing? Do I misunderstand the correct behavior?

Comment: That sounds broken; GDB prints lowest element first (at least on my system with GDB 11.2).  Your vector has 2 low zeros before the first -1 element, but your output integer has 5 low bits.  (Your vector has 5 high zeros; is it possible it's printing it backwards?  Maybe try `vpcmpeqd %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0` / `vpmovmskb %ymm0, %eax` to make sure you get `0x00ff`.  And/or `vperm2i128 $0x08,%ymm0,%ymm0,%ymm0` to copy the low to high and zero the low half, so you'd get `0xff00`.)  GDB bugs are possible, so you could also store your vector to memory and look at it with `x`, or write code to print it.

Comment: Anyway, yes your expectation is correct, but byte-reversing the vector would also explain the result you get, since it has more symmetry than one might like in a test case.  Almost certainly either a GDB bug.  (Or user error if you were looking at the register at the wrong time or something. An [mcve] with source and a copy/paste of a GDB session could confirm it; also include GDB version number.)

Comment: (Oh, I mixed up your actual vs. expected.  Your actual result is correct for GDB printing lowest-address-first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observing is not intuitive, but there’s no bugs anywhere. Visual Studio debugger prints about the same thing:

```
eax,b   0b00000100000100000100000100000100  unsigned int
```

When debuggers are printing SIMD vectors, they print them as if they were stored in memory. This means the first lane is on the left in the debugger. Visual Studio debugger is a GUI app, it shows expandable arrays, the first element is on top and it also shows 0-based indices near the elements.

When printing a single number however, the least significant digit is on the right, and the most significant digit is on the left. So when you look at `uint32_t` number printed as binary, you should keep in mind the bit order is reversed there: the first bit #0 is on the right of the string, the last bit #31 is on the left of the string.

In your AVX vector, the first byte with the high bit set is in the lane #2 (assuming zero-based numbering), second one is in lane #8. If you look at your binary result, you’ll notice bits #2 and #8 **from the right** are set in that number.